# JQuery/JavaScript: Enable and disable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code example:

```
$( "#new_warehouse" ).onClick(function() {
  $('.js-dependent-fields:hidden').children().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

It adds a "disabled" to all childs of my js-dependent-fields div, if `style="display: none;"`. How can I revert this when the js-dependent-fields div gets visible?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use correctly `.on()` listener with `.click()` event with a callback function in the `prop()` method:

```
$( "#new_warehouse" ).on('click', function() {
   $('.js-dependent-fields').children().prop('disabled', function(){
      return $(this).is(':hidden');
   });
});
```

Thing to notice is that the target element is a class selector so it would return a collection so, we have to look for each one with the `$(this)` and check if it is `:visible`.

Comment: This is almost what I need. One strange thing: The div that appears (with a select form in it) is disabled (because it's a child). Only if I click again into the disabled field, it gets active. What should I change?

Comment: `.on('change', function()` did it for me!

Comment: @Harakiri good to see that, this way it worked for you. Actually it was really hard to understand what actually was going on at your end because the working example was there, i suggest you to add a small test case in the question for better understanding. and lastly you are welcome.

Comment: How can I change the code in order to work with all forms and not only with id ""#new_warehouse"" ?

Comment: `#new_warehouse` what element is this? is it div placed like a first child in the form.

Comment: As ids are unique for each element, so you can add a common class name to access all the target elements just like: `$('form > .targetEl').children()....`

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the effect using :visible pseudo class selector. But for your need you can use like this:

```
$('.js-dependent-fields:hidden').children().prop('disabled', 
   $('.js-dependent-fields').is(':hidden')//sets true if hidden else false
);
```

Comment: wouldn't `$('.js-dependent-fields').is(':hidden')` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more apt code would be

```
    $( "#new_warehouse" ).onClick(function() {
        $('.js-dependent-fields').children().prop('disabled',  
           $('.js-dependent-fields').is(':hidden') ? 
             true : false );
     });
```

Comment: You can just pass `$('.js-dependent-fields').is(':hidden')` no need for ternary operator.